# Complete Residue System Proof - n elements

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Theorem: Let $n$ be a natural number. Every $complete$ $residue$ $system$ $modulo$ $n$ contains $n$ elements.

The definition of a $complete$ $residue$ $system$ $modulo$ $n$ as given in our text: Let $k$ and $n$ be natural numbers. A set {$a_1$, $a_2$, ... ,$a_k$} of integers is called a $complete$ $residue$ $system$ $modulo$ $n$ if every integer is congruent modulo $n$ to exactly one element of the set.

This the first theorem we are given following this definition. I am completely lost. How do I even begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every integer can be written as $K = qn + r$, where $r \in [0,n)$ and both $r,q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now working modulo $n$ we have:

$$K = qn + r \equiv r \pmod n$$

Now how many integers are in the interval $r\in [0,n)$?

Comment: Did you mean to ask how many integers are in the interval [0,n)? There are n integers in that interval. I am just wondering if we are still including 0 and excluding n.

Comment: Yes. Simple typo, I've edited the answer, it's better now.

Comment: Ah, this makes so much sense! So working through this in my head now I have: every integer can be written as K=qn+r, r∈[0,n). Obviously qn+r≡r(modn), since n|(qn+r-r). By the definition of a complete residue system, every integer (qn+r) is congruent mod n to exactly one element of the set. Since we wrote qn+r≡r(modn), this set is all of the possible values of r, of which there are n. QED.

Comment: @Paige Yes, that's it. You can use the fact that every integer can be reduced to a element from the complete residue system modulo $n$

Comment: I may be incorrect but it seems to me the solutions discussed only address the case that a complete residue system cannot have more than n elements but the proposition is that a complete residue system has strictly n elements. if every integer can be written in the form qn + r where r is in [0,n-1) what has been said that guarantees every integer in the interval will be congruent to some integer? It seems that as it stands it is still possible for a complete residue system to have less than n elements.